# How can I get styled attributes in onConfigurationChanged()?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the locale of the app at runtime, using [the official android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#androidx-impl), while handling the locale configuration changes manually to avoid the main activity recreation. But there is a compound view that has a custom `labelText` attribute, which I need to update with a new localized string on every configuration change:

```java
public class SomeScreen extends Fragment {
    private TextInputCustom phoneField; // custom compound view
    private Button buttonEn;
    private Button buttonDe;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...  (inflate view, etc...)
        
        buttonEn = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonEn);
        buttonEn.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            LocaleListCompat appLocale = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en");
            AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale);
        });

        buttonDe = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDe);
        buttonDe.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            LocaleListCompat appLocale = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("de");
            AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale);
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        phoneField.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // ...
}
```

```java
public class TextInputCustom extends ConstraintLayout {
    private TextView label;
    private @Nullable AttributeSet attributeSet;

    public TextInputCustom(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.attributeSet = attrs;
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.TextInputCustom);
        String labelText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.TextInputCustom_labelText);
        //     ^^^
        label.setText(labelText);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that `labelText` obtained from `typedArray` always returns `null` in the `onConfigurationChanged` method. Debugger shows that `getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(...)` returns wrong or zero values.
Is there a way to get attribute values from xml layout of a component during configuration change? So that I could specify string in the layout like so:

```xml
    <TextInputCustom
        app:labelText="@string/password"
        ...
    />
```

versions:

- targetSdk: 33
- minSdk: 16
- `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1`
- `com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0`